# Windows 8.1 Modern UI sidebar

Tags: windows

I am seeking for a sidebar supporting Modern UI apps. Something like Gadgets bar from Win7, but with Modern UI apps.
Googling only gave me Metrosidebar, which is fine, but uses some weird unofficial store.
I only want to host standard Modern UI apps in a neat column at the side of my screen.
Is it possible?

Or maybe it will be possible in Win10 somehow. They have apps running in windows.